# My SD card reader doesn't work

Tags: fedora, sd-card

When inserting an SD card in my laptop's internal card reader, it's not being recognized by my system. I've tried 2 micro-SD cards with an adapter and 1 SD card, which all work perfectly fine on Windows, which means I can rule out the issue being the reader or the SD-card. The SD cards can be accessed by an external SD card reader via USB, so the SD is not in any way inaccessible on Linux.

I have a HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop-dk1xxx running Fedora Linux 39 Workstation with kernel version 6.7.9-200.fc39x86_64. My laptop does recognize my card reader:

```
tygoe@fedora:~$ lspci --nnvv
...
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller [1aea:6625]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8742]
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at a5300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: alcor_pci
    Kernel modules: alcor_pci
...
```

When running `lsusb`, it isn't being recognized, and in `lsblk` or `sudo fdisk -l`, there's no SD card to be found:

```
tygoe@fedora:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3        8:3    0 464.2G  0 part /home
                                      /
zram0       252:0    0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 475.7G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   582M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   530M  0 part 
tygoe@fedora:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
...

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
...

Disk /dev/zram0: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 2097152 sectors
...
```

When inserted, there is also no file in `/media` and in `/dev` there's not any mmcblk device.

While checking `dmesg`, I saw an error though: first it fails while initializing the SD card, and then about every 10 seconds, it's saying 'Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt', which is very similar to [this probe](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=412bc51f72):

```
[ 4446.354315] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[ 4456.593240] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 4466.833227] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 4477.074294] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 4487.313135] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 4497.553234] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 4507.793392] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 4518.033422] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 4528.273424] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
```

When scrolling back, I also see this (I don't really know if it has something to do with this, but it could be something):

```
[ 1141.382030] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 1181.255355] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error message received from 0000:00:1d.6
[ 1181.255368] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[ 1181.255370] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:   device [8086:06b6] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 1181.255371] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6:    [12] Timeout               
[ 1232.518117] alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
```

Is there anyone who can help me? [This](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c) is the driver's source (included in the kernel) if anyone is able to do something with it.

Comment: On a quick search, others have reported a problem with a ``Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller [1aea:6625]``. E.g. [Device 'Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller'](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci%3A1aea-6625-103c-8745) has an entry for a HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 17-cd1xxx with a status of _failed_ reporting ``when SD card is plugged in, dmesg only shows this on repeat every 10 seconds: alcor_sdmmc alcor_sdmmc.0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.``

Comment: As for the ``pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error message received from 0000:00:1d.6`` error, from the current information not sure if related to the SD card issue. Can you edit the question and include the output of ``lspci -nn -v -t`` to show the PCI bus topology. This is to see if the ``0000:00:1d.6`` device is in the path to the the SD card reader.

Comment: @ChesterGillon The first link you sent I had already mentioned in my post (It wasn't any help though), and I'll post the output of `lspci -nn -v -t` in a few hours when I'm home